# Calculate hours and minutes from date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display the difference in hours, and minutes between `created_at` and the current date and time.

currently, I have

```
{{ $calls['created_at']->hour }} hrs, {{ $calls['created_at']->minute}} mins
```

How can I achieve this

Comment: Where is `$calls['created_at']` coming from?

Comment: use Carbon diffForHumans method

Comment: `created_at` is coming from laravel timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get **exactly** what you get now using **Carbon**, use `->diffForHumans` as

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$diff = $calls['created_at']->diffForHumans(null, true, true, 2);

echo str_replace(['h', 'm'], ['hrs', 'mins'], $diff);
```

> **Updated** : From your comments, I assume `$calls['created_at']` is a `Carbon` object

Comment: I tried inserting the code in my controller after declaring the `$calls` variable but I get `Undefined index: created_at` error. I think it doesn't read the value of `created_at` which is been fetched from the database and stored in an array on the  `$calls` variable...please how do I fix this...the  `$calls` variable works fine

Comment: What's the dd of $calls?

Comment: It fetches the required data from the `calls table` in my database.

Comment: To sort out the issue i need to know at least the dd of `$calls['created_at']`

Comment: It is throwing the same `Undefined index: created_at` error

Comment: Does the  `$calls` array have `created_at` ? Without seeing the dump of `$calls` cannot move further. can you update the question with the dump ?

Comment: Yes...its generated from laravel's timestamp

Comment: I assume it's a `carbon` object and updated the answer. If `created_at` is nullable, please add further validations to the given snippet.

Comment: Can you update the question with `$calls` dump ? `$calls` is a mystery object for us. Without it, your problem cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$created_at = Carbon::parse($calls['created_at']);
$diffHuman = $created_at->diffForHumans($now);  // 3 Months ago
$diffHours = $created_at->diffInHours($now);  // 3 
$diffMinutes = $created_at->diffInMinutes($now)   // 180
```

Comment: How can I write and call this method from the controller?

Comment: Just copy paste this code snippet and check the last 3 variables. you will get results as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try `{{ $calls->created_at->diffForHumans() }}`

Comment: Are you sure about this? Does `$calls->created_at` have such a method?

Comment: Yes, If `$vinfo` is Eloquent: Collection and `created_at` is one of its property then you can use `{{ $vinfo->created_at->diffForHumans() }}` in your blade template to get results like "1 day ago"

Comment: I want to get the hours and minutes not the days...I already know about `diffForHumans()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the carbon class to convert to seconds then you can convert it to hours

```
$seconds = Carbon::diffInSeconds($calls['created_at']);

gmdate("H:i:s", $seconds);
```